# Связь с двумя серверами

Tags: php, хостинг, mysql

Приветствую.

Значит у меня есть 2 сервера (хостинга). Мне нужно сделать так чтобы все файлы находились на одном хостинге (назовём его host1.ru). А на втором хостинге (назовём его host2.ru) лежали файлы которые вызывали\выводили\показывали\инклудили файлы которые лежат на host1.ru. Но при действии ( нажатии на сылку к примеру ) на host2.ru мы не переходили на host1.ru.

Инклуд не подходит - больше способов не знаю :D

ps. Заранее спасибо

Comment: А, если не секрет, зачем? Просто от цели средства зависят.

Comment: Параноя :DDD А если серьёзно то просто делаю сайт и не хочется чтоб он в один прекрасный момент рухнул...рухнул в руки другого человека :DDD...

Comment: Так просто пройдитесь шифровщиком zend'овским по ним. А еще проще хостинг взять и пароль от него не светить. Если не уверены в оплате - делайте сайт у себя на поддомене, после оплаты переносите.

Comment: @sh4dow Неа...Задача такая чтоб сайт был на их домене...пусть поддомене но их :DDD до оплаты надо ещё им показать готовую работу :DDDD уже на домене...вообщем их хостинг есть...и надо на нём сделать сайт...ну вот хочу чтоб оттуда с моего хостинга брались файлы или выводилось. Вообщем всеми силами препятствовать утечки файлов и кода :DDD

Comment: Это плохое условие, вас спокойно могут кинуть. причем по хорошему предлогу (вы задержали срок на 6 часов, сайт мы уже скачали, но он нам не понравился и пр). По-человечески делается либо у себя с постоплатой, либо у них с предоплатой. Можно у них хотя бы с авансом, если есть доверие. 

Если условия не изменить - Zend Encoder. С некоторых пор найти дешифровщик очень трудно. *А ломаный encoder - просто)*

*Поправьте, если плохо искал*

Comment: Ога...Щас нагуглю что это :D Спасибо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всю статику (html, js, css, jpg ...) подключай по полному URL, например: http:// host2.ru/file.jpg. Для PHP-библиотек отключи интерпритацию, или переименуй во что-то типа *.inc. И, подключай, тоже, по URL.

Но, индексный файл, все-же, должен быть на host1.ru.

Еще можно с iframe поиграться...

Comment: Может я нуп...Но как ты собрался подключать файлы по полному URL ( я про .inc ) если

     include(); 

Не подходит?...Я больше методов не знаю :D только если интерпретированный файл...Но там как не крути уже будешь при нажатии на ссылки на host1.ru попадать.

Comment: Смотри [пример 3][1]. Там показано как можно подключать либы по URL. И не забудь про интерпретацию. Если их обработает php-интерпретатор то вместо библиотеки в include попадет результат ее выполнения.

  [3]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

Comment: Нет...Инклуд не работает проверял файлы .txt, .php, .inc не хочет подключать...И пхп разметкой и без...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: В том то и заковырка...Не хочет хостер давать включить её...Так бы я не ломал голову :DDD

Comment: Еще можно попробовать читать файл с помощью `CURL`, а выполнять через `eval()`. Но это еще тот костыль.

А, вообще, проще сказать заказчику, что пока не заплатите сайт будет висеть на моем хосте, и не парить себе мозг :)

Comment: :D сейчас пойду и скажу :DDDD Ладно и на этом спасибо :)